# How can I reuse sub function in hashes

Tags: perl

```
use strict;
use warnings;

#My sample bbl content

my $sample = '
reflistStart
\bibtype{Article}%
\bibinfo{title}{Sample Title}
reflistEnd
reflistStart
\bibtype{Book}%
\bibinfo{title}{Sample Title}
reflistEnd
reflistStart
\bibtype{Proceedings}%
\bibinfo{title}{Sample Title}
reflistEnd
';

$sample=~s#reflistStart((?:(?!reflist(?:Start|End)).)*)reflistEnd#my $fulcnt=$&;
if($fulcnt=~m/\\bibtype\{article\}/i)
{
    $fulcnt = ArticleReplacement($fulcnt);
}
elsif($fulcnt=~m/\\bibtype\{book\}/i)
{
    $fulcnt = BookReplacement($fulcnt);
}
elsif($fulcnt=~m/\\bibtype\{proceedings\}/i)
{
    $fulcnt = ProceedingsReplacement($fulcnt);
}
($fulcnt);
#ges;

sub ArticleReplacement
{
    my $arttext = shift;
    $arttext=~s/\\bibinfo\{title\}/\\bibinfo\{articletitle\}/g;
    return $arttext;
}
sub BookReplacement
{
    my $arttext = shift;
    $arttext=~s/\\bibinfo\{title\}/\\bibinfo\{booktitle\}/g;
    return $arttext;
}
sub ProceedingsReplacement
{
    my $arttext = shift;
    $arttext=~s/\\bibinfo\{title\}/\\bibinfo\{proceedingstitle\}/g;
    return $arttext;
}
```

## Output:

```
reflistStart
\bibtype{Article}%
\bibinfo{articletitle}{Sample Title} #title changed as articletitle
reflistEnd
reflistStart
\bibtype{Book}%
\bibinfo{Booktitle}{Sample Title}
reflistEnd
reflistStart
\bibtype{Proceedings}%
\bibinfo{Proceedingstitle}{Sample Title}
reflistEnd;
```

Here I am doing for each reference types (article, book, Proceedings) in "IF" Conditions. Hence my question, there is any other by using hashes for example:

```
 my %Refstyles = ( 'article' => \&ArticleReplacement, 'book' => \&BookReplacement, ... );
```

Comment: I think you need to explain what it is that you're trying to do. Also, `print $Refstyles{$1}` will print something like `CODE(0x1e8fea0)` and won't call the subroutine at all.

Comment: Updated my Question

Comment: No, even after your edit, it's really not clear what you're trying to do or what problems you are having.

Comment: Again updated... I dont know here how to explain more clear

Comment: Well, for a start, you could tell us what you are trying to achieve. And what problems you are having. What output are you expecting? What are you actually getting? What are the differences?

Comment: Output should be same what I have updated (\bibinfo{title} changed \bibinfo{articletitle}). The way I need to do in different format. I am using _if else_ hence I expecting this in via hashes.

Comment: Each and every references I am using _If else_ in coding. In this case I need to do in different way using hashes and sub routines.

Comment: Don't give more information in comments. Please edit the information into your question. Delete all of the content of your question and start again. Start with "I have the following data" (and explain what the data is). Go on with "I want to change the data by (describe the transformation)". Then "I expect this output.... but I'm getting this ..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. I think I understand. Your question is something like this:

> I have some TeX documents which have a `\bibtype{xxx}` definition followed by a `\bibinfo{title}` definition on the following line.
>
> I need to change the `title` in the `bibinfo` definition using the `bibtype` value to determine the replacement text.
>
> And I'd like to do that using a hash of subroutine references, where each subroutine changes one type of `bibtype`.

Is that accurate?

If it is, I think you're overcomplicating things. I think you can do this without subroutines or references or anything like that. I would write that like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

# Hash that maps the bibtype to the title type
my %subs = (
  article     => 'articletitle',
  book        => 'booktitle',
  proceedings => 'proceedingstitle',
);

# Turn the keys of that hash into a regex
my $match = join('|', keys %subs);

my $sample = '
reflistStart
\bibtype{Article}%
\bibinfo{title}{Sample Title}
reflistEnd
reflistStart
\bibtype{Book}%
\bibinfo{title}{Sample Title}
reflistEnd
reflistStart
\bibtype{Proceedings}%
\bibinfo{title}{Sample Title}
reflistEnd
';

# A slightly complex substitution operator.
# We match all of the text that we're interested in (over two lines).
# We capture the bibtype and then replace the title with the new
# title string as looked up in our %subs hash.
# Another slight cleverness, is the use of \K and (?=...) to match
# bits of the string that we don't want to replace. See perldoc perlre
# for more details.
# Oh, and we use /g to change all of the titles in one go.
$sample =~ s/bibtype\{($match)\}%\n\\bibinfo\{\Ktitle(?=\})/$subs{lc $1}/eig;

print $sample;
```

Running this gives the following output:

```
reflistStart
\bibtype{Article}%
\bibinfo{articletitle}{Sample Title}
reflistEnd
reflistStart
\bibtype{Book}%
\bibinfo{booktitle}{Sample Title}
reflistEnd
reflistStart
\bibtype{Proceedings}%
\bibinfo{proceedingstitle}{Sample Title}
reflistEnd
```

Which looks right to me.

Comment: Woww.. Fantastic...I got it.